# Добавление новой строки в DataGrid через List<>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, list, datagrid

Всем доброго времени суток.

Прошу помочь разобраться.

На форме WPF есть `DataGrid` добавляю в нее новую строку через кнопку следующим образом:

```
private void AddTask_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<GridСustoms> customs = new List<GridСustoms>
    {
        new GridСustoms 
        {
            Title = TitleText.Text,
            Description = DescriptionText.Text,
            Priority = PriorityText.Text, 
            Status = StatusText.Text,
            CreationDate = CreationD.Text, 
            ExpirationDate = ExpirationD.Text 
        }
    };

    GridСustomsXAML.ItemsSource = customs;
    Close();
}
```

Таким образом у меня успешно создается новая строка на форме, но когда я хочу создать еще одну строку, то первая строка подменяется вновь созданной.

Прошу помочь разобраться как мне сделать добавление новых строк ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы все время перезатираете `customs`, создавая новый список через `new List<GridСustoms>`, попробуйте так:

```
public ObservableCollection<GridСustoms> customs = new ObservableCollection<GridСustoms>();

private void AddTask_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    customs.Add(
        new GridСustoms 
        {
            Title = TitleText.Text,
            Description = DescriptionText.Text,
            Priority = PriorityText.Text, 
            Status = StatusText.Text,
            CreationDate = CreationD.Text, 
            ExpirationDate = ExpirationD.Text 
        }
    );

    Close();
}
```

Свойство `GridСustomsXAML.ItemsSource = customs;` нужно прописать на этапе инициализации, дабы не словить `NullReferenceException` при добавлении в коллекцию.

Comment: Способ который вы описали выше не сработал, но удалось решить через ObservableCollection. Спасибо вам за помощь

Comment: public ObservableCollection<GridСustoms> Сustoms = new ObservableCollection<GridСustoms>();

customs.Add(new GridСustoms { Title = TitleText.Text, Description = DescriptionText.Text, Priority = PriorityText.Text, Status = StatusText.Text, CreationDate = CreationD.Text, ExpirationDate = ExpirationD.Text });

Comment: @Ivan да-да, внес правку в ответ, `ObservableCollection` тут более подходящий вариант.